# javascript add data to table cell

Tags: javascript

```
<table border='1' id='output'>

<tr>

<td>

</td>

</tr>

</table>
```

my javascript code

```
 document.getElementById("output").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

Doesnt work please help

Comment: you can assign an id to your td element and update it by find by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using JQuery u can do it easly as given below:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#output tr td").text("JQUERY HELP");
});
```

or if u want to continue with javascript u can refer other posted answers.

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/idebo4)**

Comment: should i only have to import jquery and paste your code ? will it work then ?

Comment: yeah!download jquery and use on the page where ur working on.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("output").children[0].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two things wrong:

1. That's not a valid `<table>`.

Tables have to have a `<tbody>` tag. Which is probably getting added by the browser, which means you need to go one level deeper to access the `<td>` element.

The second thing, `nodeValue` will always be null for a non-text node, which is what a `<td>` is. Instead use the `innerHTML` property to alter the element's text.

After correcting those two things, your code should look like this:

```
 document.getElementById("output").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border='1' id='output'>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

$(function(){
   $('#output td').append("blaa");
});
```

[Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/F53BN/5/)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Alex is right, there is a tbody TAg.
try below one:
document.getElementById("output").getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML="test1"